# C# strings causing memory leak in a TCP server?

Tags: c#, string, memory

Short synopsis of the issue: A tcp server I created that receives a couple connections per second from a client that sends about 5kb of xml and disconnects is growing in memory over time even though I'm not storing the xml any where.

I have a simple TCP server where I have one thread that calls AcceptTcpClient() in a while loop and then calls ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(HandleTcpClient, tcpClient) with the new TcpClient.

Now in the function that the thread pool runs(eg: HandleTcpClient) I do the following:

```
int bytesRead = networkStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, 8000);
if (bytesRead == 0) return null;
return encoder.GetString(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

After that, its calls a function that does a lock() on a Queue and adds the message to the queue. Another thread on the form will check on the queue every 50ms, call lock() on it and pop off the string .

Currently, I just pop off the string, and do:

```
XElement xe = XElement.Parse(msg);
xe = null;
```

When I start the program, the private set memory is at 34MB , within 10 hours, the memory usage is at 251MB. I made a menu item on the form that I can click that calls GC.Collect()  but that only shaves off 2MB of memory, and then the program starts to grow again.

I'm not sure why the memory would keep growing as the strings that are constantly being created should be disposed of and I'm not putting anything constantly on the heap.

I used the .NET Memory Profiler and it shows that the string,char live instances are constantly increasing.
[image]

I thought creating a new byte array might be causing the memory leaks, so I created a quick byte buffer class as seen below. Any thoughts to why the memory keeps growing ?

```
class ByteBuffer  {    static Dictionary<object, byte[]> buffers = new Dictionary<object,byte[]>();

   static public void Allocate()    {
       for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++)
       {
           buffers.Add(new object(), new byte[8000]);
       }

   }

   static ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

   static public string GetMessage( NetworkStream ns)
    {
        foreach (object o in buffers.Keys)
        {
            bool lockTaken =false;

            Monitor.TryEnter(o,TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15), ref lockTaken);

            if (lockTaken)
            {
                try
                {
                    int bytesRead = ns.Read(buffers[o], 0, 8000);
                    if (bytesRead == 0) return null;
                    return encoder.GetString(buffers[o], 0, bytesRead);
                }
                catch 
                {
                    return null;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(o);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    } }
```

Comment: Can't your memory profiler track what's holding references to the strings? If you have such a screenshot, that'd help quite a bit.

Comment: Does the server read a lot of different forms of XML, or would most of the documents have the same names for elements and attributes? Do you manually pool your nametables?

Comment: I wonder what calls GetMessage and how you manage the the strings outside the displayed code. Should you be returning in the TRY block?

Comment: @Joachim: I just started using the memory profiler, but I dont see a way to track whats holding the references
Jon Hanna: There are 2 types of xml that are received, but the strings should be disposed of, no ?
Bengie: This is how GetMessage() is called: AddMessageToQueue(ByteBuffer.GetMessage( clientStream));  where clientStream is created in a using block above this call like: using(NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream()) { ... }
The function AddMessageToQueue() simply takes the passed in string and passes it to myQueue.Enqueue(someString)

Comment: To me the suspect line is return encoder.GetString(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);  I would throw that encoder in a using in the try block, init the string outside the try, set it in the try, then return outside the try.  If this was c++, you would have a bunch of leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The strings/char arrays themselves are probably not your root problem, they are just a symptom. Most likely there are instances of other objects that *contain* string or char[] fields in them, which are being held onto.

All those `XElement` and `NameTable.Entry` objects look suspicious; are you sure you aren't leaking a reference to your `XElement` before you set it to null? Are you adding them to a parent document and forgetting to `Remove()` them again before they go out of scope?

Comment: Michael, thanks for the response. I Dequeue() a string from the queue and pass the string to a function that does:                       

try
                    {
                     
                        XElement xe = XElement.Parse(msg);

                        xe = null;
                    }
                    catch (Exception )
                    {

                    }

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how your queue grows over time, but maybe the "capacity" of it is continually growing?.

Try calling the following function in the same menu item that you created for garbage collection:

```
//Sets the capacity to the actual number of elements in the Queue<T>, if that number is less than 90 percent of current capacity.
public void TrimExcess()
```

Comment: On second thought, this probably will not be causing the **string** memory issues. However, if you are going to keep the garbage collection menu item, then you may want to add this anyway. So I wont delete the post.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stands out as an obvious cause from what you have here, so here's a few different points of conjecture:

Do you have any event handlers in use, maybe `SocketAsyncEventArgs` is being used for your TCP server? If so, are they being detatched correctly?

Have you tried pooling your `NameTable`s for `XElement`? Each `XmlReader` (which `XElement.Parse` uses behind the scenes as it calls into `XElement.Load`) has an `XmlNameTable`, either one passed to the constructor explicitly or one created by the constructor - depending on which constructor override is used. As it encounters strings it has to deal with (pretty much all prefixes, local names, processing-instruction target names and a few others) is stored in this table for performance reasons (sort of like string.Intern but to its own private intern-pool, and with a random element to its hashing algorithm to defeat hash-collision based DoS attacks). If you share name tables between readers processing the same sorts of documents (which in your case would mean replacing the Parse calls with explicit creation of an `XmlReader` followed by a call to `XElement.Load`), then it has two effects:

1. It makes the parsing marginally faster provided it is indeed seeing much the same element and attribute names each time.
2. It changes the memory use in a way comparable to `string.Intern` - that is to say you can make things a lot worse if you end up storing lots of strings that'll never be seen again, but you can make it a lot better if you are indeed hitting the same strings each time.

`NameTable` isn't thread-safe, but you can have a pool of `NameTable`s, return each to the pool when you're done with it, and take one from the pool for the next reader unless the pool is empty. Pretty much, you're replacing a churn of allocated and dying (but perhaps not gen-0 dying) `NameTable`s with n long-lived `NameTable`s where n is the most simultaneous parsing threads your application has had at a time. http://hackcraft.github.com/Ariadne/documentation/html/T_Ariadne_Pool_1.htm is a class created for doing this sort of pooling.

Does your handling of `TcpClient` dispose it when it's done? I imagine it'd a bigger hit than just holding onto some memory (that is, I'd expect you to have it collapse with a lack of other resources before memory that was held onto for too long hurt), but if they were making it into gen 2 while referenced it could be a very long time before they were finalised, and then when they make it to the finalisation queue they'll be another GC root until finally finalised. While I can't see it hurting this much, it could still be worth looking at.

Related to the pooling idea. Are there strings you would be better off interning because you see the same strings repeatedly (and let their newly created copies get gen-0-collected). Alternatively, have you some code that is interning aggressively when it probably shouldn't? Interning can be a great way to reduce memory usage, and an even greater way to massively increase it!

Comment: Thanks for the response Jon Hanna ! I commented out the lines with creating XElement or calling parse after seeing your comment, but memory still grows. Also, I call tcpClient.Close() after I add the message to the queue. I noticed I get a couple hundred connections within 5 secs and when I look in TcpView (the program) there are tons of TIME_WAIT connections.

Comment: @AriesOntheHorizon That's because you don't handle TCP graceful shutdown correctly. For example, when `Read` returns `0`, that means the other end of the connection is shutting down - you should do so immediatelly as well. Without graceful shutdown, TCP connections will survive about 2 minutes after they're "terminated".